# laravel join three tables

Tags: laravel, join, union

I have three tables that are as follows:

**invent_accessory**
id,code,detail,is_length

**invent_price_accessory**
id,invent_accessory_id_fk,price,color

**invent_price_accessory_length**
id,invent_accessory_id_fk,price,color

how do i combine these three tables so that i can get **id,code,detal,is_length,price,color**

i have done following but it doesnt not return any data:

```
 public function getAccessoryInventPrice(){

  $accessory=DB::table('invent_accessory')
        ->select('invent_accessory.id as accessory_id')
        ->join('invent_price_accessory','invent_price_accessory.invent_accessory_id_fk','=','invent_accessory.id')
        ->join('invent_price_accessory_length','invent_price_accessory_length.invent_accessory_id_fk','=','invent_accessory.id')
      ->get();

  return $accessory;

 }
```

I am guessing that I have to do Union between **invent_price_accessory** and **invent_price_accessory_length** first then join with **invent_accessory**? How do i do this? pls help.

Comment: thank u for pointing it out.it was just a typing error. i have edited my post but it doesnt solve  my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was right!! i was able to solve this by:

```
  public function getAccessoryInventPrice(){


    $data1=\DB::table('invent_price_accessory')->select('accessory_code_id','color_id','rate');
    $data2=\DB::table('invent_price_acc_length')->select('accessory_code_id','color_id','rate')
              ->union($data1);

    $query= \DB::table(\DB::raw("({$data2->toSql()}) as invent_price"))

            ->join('invent_accessory','invent_price.accessory_code_id','=','invent_accessory.id')
            ->join('invent_color','invent_price.color_id','=','invent_color.id')
            ->select('invent_accessory.id','code','sl_detail','is_length','rate','invent_color.name')
            ->orderBy('invent_accessory.id','asc')
            ->get();
              return $query;

 }
```